# Getting location via a web application being run in a WebView

Tags: android, html, geolocation

m.google.com somehow requests the current location when loaded in Android's browser.

I want to do the same thing from a web page being loaded into a WebView in my own application.  Is the only way to go about this with `WebView.addJavascriptInterface()`, or is there already a javascript interface available for webapps to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done via HTML5.

Lookup here the Javascript: 
http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html