# How to enable share location in android app

Tags: android, mobile, gps

I am trying to convert one mobile website (http://swadd.bvm.mx/index.php) into Android app

But the Share location is not working. http://swadd.bvm.mx/saferide.php

In pc browser it asks to share the location but in mobile app, when you hit "share location" then there is not response.

Comment: for this you have to develop native android code to get location.. and send it..

Comment: Maybe this will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511195/getting-location-via-a-web-application-being-run-in-a-webview

Comment: "for this you have to develop native android code to get location.. and send it" - W R O N G  .... HTML 5 geolocation services work just fine. If you don't know what you are talking about, please do not post and mislead others.   http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html